# HAProxy - how to append client ip in X-Client-IP and X-Forwarded-For headers?

Tags: haproxy

I have a problem with HAProxy server. I want to forward in header a client IP. I almost done it, but there is interesting case and I can't figure it out. I need to write client IP in 2 places in header, in X-CLIENT-IP and X-FORWARDED-FOR tag's.

The problem is: When I use

```
option http-server-close
option forwardfor
```

On target server I see in header X-FORWARDED-FOR=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(client ip) but there is no x-client-ip header.

When I use:

```
option forwardfor header X-Client-IP
option http-server-close
```

On target server I see header X-CLIENT-IP=xxx.xxx.xxx(client IP) but X-FORWARDED-FOR=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(HAProxy ip)

I need to see on target header where X-CLIENT-IP and X-FORWARDED-FOR has value of client IP.

I try to mix configurations like

```
 option forwardfor
 option forwardfor header X-Client-IP
 option http-server-close
```

No efect. I can not also install any modules. The target is IIS.

Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try setting up custom header, like this:

```
http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[src]
```

Or, you can even copy it from X-Forwarded-For header, I think syntax would go something like:

```
http-request set-header X-Client-IP req.hdr_ip([X-Forwarded-For])
```

Comment: Second option give me in header x-client-ip=req.hdr_ip(%5bX-Forwarded-For%5d), so something is wrong. But I'l try first one.

Comment: First resolution http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[src] works perfect.

Comment: Last example is wrong, the right rule is: http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[req.hdr_ip(X-Forwarded-For)]

Comment: X-Client-IP and X-Forwarded-For have different purposes. It's not safe to copy X-Forwarded-For, because HAProxy can return value sent by client.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use both, you'll need to add the second with an `http-request` keyword.

```
# add X-FORWARDED-FOR
option forwardfor
# add X-CLIENT-IP
http-request add-header X-CLIENT-IP %[src]
```

Comment: I think set-header is better to remove malicious headers sent from client.

Comment: @Der_Meister You might be right, but I don't see how that has any relevance to this question or answer. Care to elaborate?

Comment: The purpose of X-Client-IP header is to tell backend the real IP address of the connection, not a random value from an incoming header. It's not mentioned in the question, I just want to warn future readers.

Comment: Again, you might be right but in this example, the `X-CLIENT-IP` isn't being set by the client, but rather by HAProxy based on the source IP. I'd suggest leaving these comments on questions where it *is* relevent so as not to confuse readers.

Comment: `add-header` doesn't remove the `X-CLIENT-IP` that may have been set by the client. This is why @Der_Meister recommended using `set-header` instead. I suggest editing your answer to use `set-header` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested answer above that did not work for KacproSo just needed to read the value by adding `&[...]`, so this should work fine:

```
http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[req.hdr_ip([X-Forwarded-For])]
```

Comment: With this one you get the last IP on the list. The client IP is the first one so, get it with their number position:
`http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[req.hdr_ip([X-Forwarded-For,1])]`

Answer (score 1):

Trying on HAproxy 1.7 this is the correct syntax that makes this work, without the square brakets around X-Forwarded-For

```
   http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[req.hdr_ip(X-Forwarded-For)]
```

Answer (score 0):

this one works best for me:

```
backend example
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-For %[src]
```

Answer (score -2):

Your can install a module called mod_rpaf on your backend server(s). This copies the X-FORWARDED-FOR IP to the X-CLIENT-IP. For more information see [this](https://trick77.com/haproxy-and-real-ip-addresses-in-apache2-using-the-rpaf-module/). On Windows you should have similar modules, something like X-Forwarded-For ASAPI filters.

Comment: He cannot install any modules..